# Need a label generator utility

Tags: java, graphs, charts, utility

I need a utility that can be integrated with Java and can generate label (attached) by passing the values dynamically. The utility can be paid.
[image: example image of label to generate]

I am looking for multiple labels on a sheet, such as A4 sheets.

Comment: One giant label, multiple labels, A4 sheets ?

Comment: Yes like A4 sheet

Comment: Based on your posted image it is unclear what labels should be generated from this. Should every rectangle end up on a sperate label?

Comment: Its custom. Tool should be able to define the structure.